# How close to an integer can a polynomial root be?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose I have a polynomial $p(x) = a_n x^n + ... + a_0$ where $a_n, \dots, a_0$ are integers. I would like to show that any root of this polynomial is either an integer or is far from an integer. That is, if $r$ denotes the fractional part of a root $x$, I want to show that either $r = 0$ or $r > w$ for some real valued $w$.

If the polynomial $p$ has degree one this is easy --- I know either $w = 0$ or $w \geq \frac{1}{|a_1|}$.

Is there a similar bound that can be shown for arbitrary polynomials, where the minimum non-zero value of $w$ can be bounded in terms of the sizes of $a_0, \dots, a_n$?

Comment: There are a couple of cases. The polynomial might have a root at the nearby integer $k$ or not. If so, perhaps root separation bounds are good enough. If not, then the polynomial has a value at least $1$ away from $0$ there, and we can bound $k$ and then $p'(x)$, so the polynomial can't reach $0$ too rapidly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bound follows from the general root separation theory. See [Schonhage's 2006 paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0747717106000472/1-s2.0-S0747717106000472-main.pdf?_tid=3e55d828-be9e-11e4-8390-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1425054938_40447d42a9f0f57fb2aec11709601c4c) (Journal of Symbolic Computation)> (see inequality (3) and the discussion following, about replacing the discriminant by $1.$)

Comment: What is the bound?

Comment: There is an inequality (3), but I do not quite understand how this result answers the question, since the paper gives lower bounds on the distance between roots, but David Harris is not assuming that his polynomial has an integer root.

Comment: Well you can always apply the bound to $(x-r) \, p(x)$ where $r$ is an integer approximation to a root, but still that's surely not the best way to solve the problem...

Comment: What Noam said.

Answer (score 10):

This is a standard question in diophantine approximation.  See for example Chapter 3 of Waldschmidt's book *Diophantine Approximation of Linear Algebraic Groups*.  Here is the simplest bound that Waldschmidt gives.
Assuming $a_0\ne 0$, let $H := \max_{0\le i\le n} |a_i|$.  We will show that if $\alpha$ is any nonzero root of your polynomial, then $|\alpha| > 1/(H+1)$.

If $|\alpha| \ge 1$ then the inequality trivially holds.  Otherwise, if $|\alpha|<1$, then

$${1\over |\alpha|} \le \left|{a_0\over \alpha}\right| = \left| a_1 + a_2\alpha + \cdots + a_n \alpha^{n-1} \right| \le H(1+|\alpha| + \cdots+|\alpha|^{n-1}) < {H\over 1-|\alpha|},$$
which rearranges to $|\alpha| > 1/(H+1)$.

---

Edit: See David Lampert's comment below for how to use the above bound to answer the question that David Harris asked.

Comment: Maybe this is very naive, but if $|\alpha| \ge 1$ (the trivial case, in your answer), then $|\alpha|$ can still be *very* close to an integer, right? (I understand that one can move $\alpha$ inside the interval $[0,1)$, by "translating" the polynomial, but I guess that doesn't preserve $H$.)

Comment: Edited: Apply Waldschmidt's bound to $1/\alpha$ (assuming $a_{0}a_{n} \ne 0$) and get $|\alpha|<(H+1)$, write an upper bound (in terms of $H,n$): $H_0 \ge max |coefficients|$ for the coefficients of all polynomials $p(x+k):|k|≤(H+1),k∈Z$, and then $w>1/(H_0+1)$ (again by Waldschmidt's bound).

Comment: This answer seems to give a lower bound of a root from $0$, not from an arbitrary integer. It seems to me that you can't get a general bound which is independent of $n,$ and only depends on the $|a_{i}|$. For example, $x^{n} - 3$ has a root $\alpha$ which is only slightly larger than $1 + \frac{\log 3}{n}.$

Comment: jmc and Geoff Robinson are correct; sorry for not finishing off the argument.  David Lampert correctly explains how to use Waldschmidt's bound to answer the question that David Harris asked.  In Diophantine approximation, bounding away from zero is usually the critical part of the argument and I forgot that David asked a slightly different question.